# RPi doesn't work after formatting SD card

Tags: raspbian, sd-card

I have working with Raspberry Pi for the last month. 
I tried to downloaded the OpenCV library today and I noticed that the SD card is only using 2GB out of 8GB so stupidly, I tried to reformat my SD and downloaded the OS again, but now my RPi can't read anything.

Any tips on what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you have messed up your SD card partitions or image. To correct this, reimage the card ([instructions here](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup)). Then on first boot you will be presented an options screen. One of the options is to resize the root partition (more info on the [raspi-config file and its options](http://elinux.org/RPi_raspi-config)). That will format the card's root partition to utilize the full 8GB of your card. Note this will require a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your power supply providing sufficient power to raspberry pi device. The range of power supply should between 4.75 and 5.25 volts. You check your power problem on [Rpi Hardware](http://elinux.org/RPi_Hardware#How_Can_I_tell_if_the_power_supply_is_inadequate.3F). If the power is adequate than it may problem with your partitioning. You should format SD Card at 32fat. If you are using Linux than follow the instruction for partitioning [Oracle Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/raspberrypi-1704896.html#Essential) (Heading:**Resize the SD Card Partitions**).